# JavaFX узнать название стобцы

Tags: javafx

JavaFX TableView, брал пример от сюда (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm)
Как узнать название столбца в `startEdit()`?

```
class EditingCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {

    private TextField textField;

    public EditingCell() {
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, 
                Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                    if (!arg2) {
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Это же ваш класс, передайте имя, номер или сам объект как параметр в конструкторе.